# Installing Tia to python

Tags: python, installation

hi am new to python installation and a bit confused about what's happening here.

When I go to the terminal and typed `pip install tia` I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\target_python.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_version_info
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

When I type in terminal `python -V`. I get version as `Python 3.4.0`
but when I got to project Interpreter I see

`3.6.10 (C:\Anaconda3\envs\Conda\python.exe)`

Now the question is why does my python version on terminal show up as 3.4 when my interpreter shows 3.6.10? (and why am I not able to install tia i.e. if my python version is 3.6.10)

Any help is really appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Did you activate the environment before the pip install?

Comment: You have multiple Python installations. Try installing your package with the `pip` executable associated with the Python 3.6 installation in your Anaconda env instead of your system Python 3.4 installation, e.g. `C:\Anaconda3\envs\Conda\python.exe -m pip install tia`

Comment: thanks Brian, that was very helpful. It did install finally ! appreciate your help.

Comment: As an aside, can you link the library you’re using? I tried to find it, but the only results were unmaintained/relatively old.

Comment: @AMC no its giving me error.  now I got tia installed on my Mac when I type import tia, it doesnt give me any error. This installation which I just did is on my office laptop (windows) I am getting errors!

Comment: @PrasKam Can you clarify what is and isn’t working? You installed it on macOS without any problems, yet now on Windows you’re getting the error above?

Comment: @AMC not sure whats going wrong. My mac env had installed python version of 3.6.10 and the windows has 3.4.0 ( that is what I see when I type 'python -V' on terminal).import tia worked fine without error on Mac, but the same command gave an error.

Comment: I feel its a version issue. as my terminal shows v3.4. I created a new env with version 3.6, but when I try and activate the env (using the command 'conda activate Pk') I get 'CommandNotFoundError: 'activate' !